# pivot table / chart default sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

What is default sorting for excel 2010 pivot table and charts I have a "Year month Week" column in my data sheet which I am using as row label, excel pivot table renders it arbitrarily

like in data sheet I have data in the following order

```
2010 October Week 1
2010 September Week 1
2010 September Week 2 
2010 September Week 3
2010 September Week 4
```

but when I use this in pivot table it generates row labels as

```
2010 October Week 1
2010 September Week 3
2010 September Week 2 
2010 September Week 4
2010 September Week 1
```

I want pivot table to show row labels exactly in the same order as it is in data sheet

Comment: any one please :(

Comment: I don't see that in Excel 2010, using the sample values you provided. By default Excel will sort the rows alphabetically, and the values you posted are already ordered that way.  Maybe you have odd spaces in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, per [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP005202971.aspx):

> Excel uses the following order for ascending sort: numbers, text,
>   logical values, error values such as #REF! and #VALUE!, and then blank
>   cells.

It might be a good idea to check formatting to ensure the data is being stored correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on the field in the Pivot Table - choose "More sort options" then an appropriate order, then "More Options" and make sure it is ticked to automatically re-sort if new data is added.

Your biggest problem here will be the sort order is arbitrary - if you choose alphabetical this will not work very well for the month names. You would be better to either use a week number across the whole year or actual dates (eg for week commencing 3/10/10, 10/10/10, 17/10/10 etc).